# How to force IntelliJ IDEA to show welcome screen again?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ has a very good welcome screen, but after first use, when I open IntelliJ the next time, it will open my last opened project directly. But what if I want to revisit the welcome screen? Is there a way to do it without restarting IntelliJ?
I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/welcome-screen.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Close all open project windows (**File | Close Project**).

Comment: @PeitiPeterLi [File]-[Close Project]

Comment: When doing so by x-ing Intellij, it is closing on Windows. To trigger the welcome screen, the action File->"close project" needs to be used instead.

Comment: This is easily the best answer! Exactly what I was looking for, although I'm not sure why it is the not the most upvoted.

Answer (score 115):

I'm using not IntelliJ but WebStorm however, maybe same settings.

how about this?

> [File] - [Settings] - [Appearance & Behavior] - [System Settings]
>   uncheck "Reopen last project on startup"

Comment: This method is good but it needs restart IntelliJ which is not I want. I want to keep this config to reopen last opened project.

Comment: Thanks, this is what everyone on Google is looking for.

Comment: This does work BUT after changing this setting, I had to explicitly close the currently open project.  From then on I had a welcome screen again (Clion).  Thanks

Comment: this is the real answer not the accepted one , please fix-it

Comment: Weird... This setting fixes it for the Windows IntelliJ. On my Mac, there is no need to disable this option as I get the welcome screen by default.

Comment: in windows 10, webstorm 2021.2.2 version, this setting always open welcome screen on startup. So this one I was looking for and thanks, it's working totally fine

Answer (score 24):

Sometimes I want to come back to the Welcome screen only to see the list of recent projects with a little more details than a simple list. However, I don't want to close the open project.

If that's your case you can to this in the version 2016.3:

**File -> Open Recent -> Manage Projects...**

#### UPDATE 1

@Gagan made a comment (below) asking about how to import a project this with this solution.

If I've understood the question correctly, you can do this either by directly opening a project (**Open...**) or by creating a new one **from Existing Sources** or **from Version Control**, as is show below:

[image]

In both cases, IntelliJ will ask you to open in the same window (which will close you current project) or in a new window (the current and the new one stay open), as show below:

[image]

Please, let us know if it works for you!

Comment: Thank you for this: I'd been looking for a solution like this for a long, long time.

Comment: This welcome screen does not show "import project" menu. How to get that? How to get import project menu while another project is still open in IntelliJ?

Comment: @Gagan I just updated the answer to check if it works for you. :)

Answer (score 12):

For IntelliJ 2020.3 use:
`File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings and uncheck Reopen projects on startup.

Answer (score 9):

Select File -> Close project.  This will cause the welcome screen to appear.

Comment: No, it does not (at least not for me).

Answer (score 1):

I saw it in the learning course

> To return to the welcome screen, just close the project window. Alternatively, you can select **File | Close Project** from the main menu. Also, you can use the File menu to open or create new projects. By default, the Learn tool window is hidden. You can open it by selecting **Help | Learn IDE Features** from the main menu.